# How to restrict tests by the group, Gradle using?

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have a similar structure of the test project:

```java
@Test(groups={"group1"})
MyTestClass1{
    @Test
    public void test1(){}
}

@Test(groups={"group2"})
MyTestClass2{
    @Test
    public void test2(){}
}

@Test(groups={"group1"}) //the same group as for the MyTestClass1
MyTestClass3{
    @Test
    public void test3(){}
}
```

build.gradle:

```
...
    task myTask1(type: Test) {
        useTestNG() {
            suites './src/test/resources/testng/myXML.xml'
        }
    }
...
```

XML:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Some smoke test" thread-count="3" parallel="tests">
    <test name="My Tests 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.mytest.MyTestClass1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="My Tests 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.mytest.MyTestClass2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>


    <test name="My Tests 3">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.mytest.MyTestClass3"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**I need to execute all tests from the `myTask1` that includes into `group1` group.**
**How to execute tests with `gradle` by `groups` parameter?**

My attempt (doesn't not work):

`gradlew myTask1 -Dgroups=group1`

Answer (score 1):

Use `includeGroups`:

```
task myTask1(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {
        suites './src/test/resources/testng/myXML.xml'
        includeGroups 'group1', 'group2'
    }
}
```

Full list of options can be found in the Javadoc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html

Comment: Thank you, but I need to manage groups from the command line - in different case I need use different groups for the same task

Comment: In addition, the `build.gradle` reproduce compilation error, when I added `includeGroups`.

Comment: Error: `Gradle DSL method not found: 'includeGroups​()'`. May be the old Gradle version?